# How to extract max value between list of date in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have successed to extract max value between two date that I have saved with sharedpref, but i don't know how to calcul if I add some dates between two previous date. it's simple if I have a little of data to compare but if I have a lot, I don't know how to compare each to extract max value between all posibilities.
[image]

Answer (score 6):

[List.reduce](https://api.dart.dev/stable/1.10.1/dart-core/List/reduce.html) and [DateTime.isAfter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/DateTime/isAfter.html) might come in handy.

```dart
final maxDate = dates.reduce((a,b) => a.isAfter(b) ? a : b)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following function which receives list of dates and return max (latest) one:

```
DateTime calcMaxDate(List<DateTime> dates){
    DateTime maxDate = dates[0];
    dates.forEach((date){
      if(date.isAfter(maxDate)){
        maxDate=date;
      }
    });
    return maxDate;
  }
```