# How to reduce a list to earliest/latest DateTime items in Dart- you know the fun type of code problem

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

I have a list of DateTime items, I want to get the earliest and latest items in that list for initializing a date range picker with min/max values based on the available data in db.

I have a tough time tracking the "behind the scenes" in loops and the reduce operator. So I'm looking for any help in making this happen efficiently, cause I'm sure I can make this happen inefficiently with 10 loops :P

What I've tried so far, random stuff that obviously is way off. Double loops and looping with reduce and .isbefore or .isAfter. Can't figure this out. My code below is a hodgepodge but it's where I'm at now. I guess another option is to simple order the list by date and take first and last, but I want to see the best solution and I think this is the right place to ask.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66585771/13945484) is what I'm trying to apply.

```
List<DateTime> dateList = [
DateTime(2021, 7, 30),
DateTime(2021, 6, 25),
DateTime(2021, 5, 14),
DateTime(2021, 4, 2),
DateTime(2021, 3, 12),
DateTime(2021, 3, 21)
];

List<DateTime> databaseDateRange() {
    var databaseDateRange = <DateTime>[];
    for (var item in dateList) {
      dateList.reduce((value, element) {
        if (value.isAfter(item)) {
        databaseDateRange.add(value.xAxis);
        }
      });
    }
    return databaseDateRange;
  }
```

Comment: `print(dateList.reduce((min, e) => e.isBefore(min)? e : min));` - the same for latest

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the **minimum** in the list (i.e **earliest** date) you can do as @the38amorim said.
I.e

```
print(dateList.reduce((min, e) => e.isBefore(min) ? e : min));
```

The above iterates through each one and checks whether the new value is before the saved one, and replaces it if that is the case, otherwise keeps the old one.

For **maximum** value in the list (i.e **latest** date), you can conversely do:

```
print(dateList.reduce((min, e) => e.isAfter(min) ? e : min));
```

More on reduce here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.18.1/dart-core/Iterable/reduce.html

Answer (score 0):

```
print(dateList.reduce((min, e) => e.isBefore(min)? e : min));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you just have a list of `DateTime` values like:

```dart
List<DateTime> dates = [DateTime(2020, 01, 02), DateTime(2022, 01, 02), DateTime(1999, 01, 02)];
```

You can simply do:

```dart
      startDateRange = dates.min; // 1999 date
      endDateRange = dates.max; // 2022 date
```